# Navbar can't open link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

So i made a navbar for my one page website, all the button work and go where i want them to go but when i click on forum anything happens, this is my HTML Code :

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="container clearfix">


        <div id="nav" class="grid_9 omega">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li data-slide="1">Acceuil</li>
                <li data-slide="2">A propos</li>
                <li data-slide="3">Serveur</li>
                <li data-slide="4">Contact</li>
                <li><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS
I share it in a ghostbin https://ghostbin.com/paste/2ctm9

I don't know what's wrong about this line `<li><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>` why this doesn't work ?

Here is my website http://gamenxtgen.multi-gaming.fr/

Comment: works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/wsbn853y/

Comment: On my website it doesn't work :/

Comment: where is your website?

Comment: http://gamenxtgen.multi-gaming.fr/ here is it

Comment: I think, you missed something, .html, .php, etc etc etc, also if you are using a scripting language in order to generate this links, you should look for the correct path to the url

Comment: The path to the url is correct mmh i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `<li><a href="../forum">Forum</a></li>`
Maybe you failed the href.

Comment: What is the address of your website?

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help. Even though the OP obviously understood your answer, it should be clear for future visitors too.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt it be something like /forum.html? Unless your are using some .htaccess the link should contain the extension.

Comment: No it's /forum/index.php and what can i add in .htaccess ?
here is mine DirectoryIndex index.php       
order deny,allow
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://gamenxtgen.multi-gaming.fr/ [NC,L,R=301]

Comment: Then try this <a href="/forum/index.php">. But you shouldnt use index.php in subfolders.

Comment: i just add this line nothing else ?

Comment: I just went to your website and checked it with Chrome dev tools. Dont know whats going on but will investigate.

Comment: It looks like you have jQuery click function with preventDefault there. Meaning when you click the link jQuery prevents the default event (going to your forum) and doing nothing. I presume you used it for the "smooth scroll" effect with anchor points somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code you have on your site:

```
var links = $('.navigation').find('li');

...

links.click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
   goToByScroll(dataslide);
});
```

The link to the forum is also in `li` so the `preventDefault` applies on it to preventing it from going to the page.

To Solve this you should define your variable more clearly (maybe add a class to it). So it does not include the link. Maybe something like

```
<li class="slides">Slide1</li>
<li class="slides">Slide2</li>
<li class="link">Forum</li>

var links = $('.slides');
```

Comment: I didn't really understand the beginning of your answer i'm sorry

Comment: The first block of code is what you have on your site. Your variable `links` is targeting all the `<li>` tags including your forum link and then it is preventing the link from working normally by the `e.preventDefault()` function. So instead of targeting all the `<li>` elements the variable shoudl be more specific by targeting for example a class.